# Using iBeacon and Passbook between and iPad app and an iPhone is there anyway to identify the person?

Tags: ios, passbook, ibeacon

Is there anyway using iBeacon and Passbook to get the identity of the person that is with in the iBeacon range? I am thinking about a VIP customer who has previously opted in for such an exchange. Thank you for your help. In the exchange between the iBeacon app running on an iPad and the Passbook running on an iPhone, want to iOS passbook identify the VIP member. Or the iPhone using it's iBeacon?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot identify which users have triggered a Pass in their Passbook when in range of an iBeacon. It is a one-way communication: the iBeacon triggers Passbook. But Passbook does not send anything to a web-service to announce this.

Apple has specifically designed it this way to maintain the security of the user. There is no way to track a user's location via Passbook. And they don't intend to change this ..

However, if you design an App that works with iBeacons you can set-up a 2-way communication. As soon as the App detects an iBeacon, it can (of course) contact your web-service to notify which user was within range ..

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is correct in that iBeacons only trigger a passive notification on the user's lock screen.  There is no callback to the server and it is impossible to know whether or not an iBeacon notification has been triggered.

However, it is possible to use iBeacons to provide differentiated service for a VIP member.

As an example, we are currently working with a major airline to use iBeacons in the business lounge and onboard the aircraft to provide personal messages to premium customers.  Our pilot has proven to be every effective, since one of the last things users do before departure is to wake their phone from sleep so they can switch it off before departure.